# Google Sheets - How to allow multiple matches in conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

Would it be possible for Google Sheets **not to stop** conditional formatting rules even after it hits its first match?

The problem:

I have a column of numerical values whose **text are color coded** based on its values, e.g. black if less than 10k, green if 10k to less than 20k, blue if between 20k and 30k, and so on.

The same cell values change **text format** to bold if the the assignee is Bob, italics if Alice, and underlined if Foo. (We should be using custom formula in conditional formatting to do this.)

The same cell values change **background color** depending how far today's date is from the deadline. (Like above, custom formula is used.)

Of course, conditional formatting **by design** stops and then applies the formatting once it hits the first matching rule. Can there be a **workaround** / **hack** for this? We can of course individually write all the matches bound by the `AND` function, but that will be writing formulas for a permutation of possibilities.

Comment: I have run into this a few times, and the only solution I could ever find is writing a conditional format for each possible condition.

Comment: I don't think there's a workaround for this, apart from what you already said. You could consider requesting this via `Help > Help Sheets improve`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are familiar but you can write custom scripts in the backend of most Google products with the Google Script language (based on JavaScript). Using this you can programmatically build conditional formatting rules. [Here is the link to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder). You will certainly need to change the code below to what you need, here is a rough idea:

```
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
let range = sheet.getRange("A1:B3");
let rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();

// this is the loop to make all of the rules
let maxVal = 1000;
low = 1;
high = 10;
let colors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','purple'];
for (let i=0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
        .whenNumberBetween(low,high)
        .setBackground(colors[i])
        .setRanges([range])
        .build();
    rules.push(rule);

//changes the low and high for the loop
low = high + 1;
high = high + 10;

sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

The code will set a different background colors for every interval. You can extend the code for as much as you need without needing to manually setting all of the rules.